# Swashbuckle Swagger C# WebApi Core 2.0 - "Produces" is empty

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I'm having trouble finding the mistake.
I've set up a little Web API with .net Core 2 and Swagger.
After I added XML support (.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();), swagger doesn't show "Response Content Type" option in the UI.

I also set "[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]" as decorator.
And yet the generated json always prints:

```
"consumes":[  

],
"produces":[  

],
```

So I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

```
    [HttpGet("Strom/{plz}")]
    [Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
    public IActionResult GetStrom(string plz)
    {
        int iplz = 0;

        if (plz.Length != 5 || !int.TryParse(plz, out iplz))
        {
            return BadRequest("Die Postleitzahl ist ungültig.");
        }
        return Ok(GetOrte(plz, 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm using IActionResult, I need to make sure to say, what type of content it's getting...

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Model.Ort.Ort>),200)]
```

That actually made it. So make sure to decorate your api correctly...